# receive all connected players on google play services realtime multiplayer game

Tags: google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

is there a way to get a list of all the ids of the players that are connected and near the user that is playing my realtime multiplayer game?

I already tried Games.Players.loadConnectedPlayers() method, but i don´t know how to use its PendingResult

I wanna use public RoomConfig.Builder addPlayersToInvite (ArrayList playerIds) 
to make the user play with only specific players

Answer (score 0):

You can use result callback as follows:

```
    Games.Players.loadConnectedPlayers(mHelper.getApiClient(), false).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Players.LoadPlayersResult>() {


                @Override
                public void onResult(LoadPlayersResult arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```